# use of Give and Take verbs

Tags: verbs

Question is about the confusion of using word give or take examination or a test for a Tutor and student?
We want to learn the use of Give and Take with respect to Examination;
 a.if we are a student then do we give/take examination?

Comment: The tutor *gives* the test and the student *takes* the test.

Comment: All words dealing with schoolwork are intensely local. Every school has their own set of words and terms and nicknames and idioms. There are no general rules. Learn the way it's used at your school and use it. When you change schools, expect it to change again.

Answer (score 0):

Think of the exam/test as a physical piece of paper, or as a booklet. The tutor/examiner GIVES the paper/booklet to you, you TAKE the paper/booklet from the tutor/examiner.

Give/take is relatively easy. You have to be careful with *write* - in English it's the examiner who writes (creates) the exam, but in many other languages it's the student who writes (out the answers to) the exam. This use of 'write' can cause confucion to native English speakers when conversing with non-native English speakers at times!

Comment: Actually, in Canadian English (but not American or British English!), it is the student who *writes* the exam.  Here is [an example](http://www.ace.utoronto.ca/ACE/tes/request_defer.html) of a webpage from a Canadian university where the student as exam-writer is used consistently.